# how to read from text file to textbox in visual basic 1 line every hit on button

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have files type .txt (Text File) and it's have multiple line and i have these pictures

i want to make program generate fake information

Mean: when some one hit generate button it's ready from text file and fill textbox in visual basic

every hit(press) on Generate Button make program generate new information from text files (.txt)

i tried a lot ways:

Code:

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
```

Code:

```
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt", _
   System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
```

and this

Code:

```
 Dim oFile as System****.File
Dim oRead as System****.StreamReader
oRead = oFile.OpenText(“C:\test.txt”)
```

and this

Code:

```
 Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt"
        Dim objReader As New System.I--O.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
        TextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
```

Code:

```
' Form Load :
Dim text As String = MsgBox("text you want to make the form remember it.")
Or new Sub :
Code:
Private Sub Text
text
Code:
' Button Click :
Text()
```

Code:

```
    Dim path As String = "THE FILE PATH" 'The file path
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
        Dim lineIndex As Integer = 2 ' The index of the line that you want to read
        For i As Integer = 0 To lineIndex - 1
            reader.ReadLine()
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadLine


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = ReadLineFromTxt("THE TXT FILE PATH", 0) '0 is the line index
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReadLineFromTxt(ByVal path As String, ByVal lineIndex As Integer) As String
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
        For I As Integer = 0 To lineIndex - 1
            reader.ReadLine()
        Next
        Return reader.ReadLine()
    End Function
End Class
```

These ways take from members in this fourm:
 http://www.mpgh.net/forum/33-visual-basic-programming/693165-help-how-can-i-generate-text-txt-file-textbox-when-button-click-2.html

if are these ways working please tell me how to use it in best way

i have Visual studio 2012 and updated 1

With all due respect

Comment: how large is the file?

Comment: Please clarify the specific goal you are trying to accomplish, or provide an example of what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are reading from a file and displaying lines on the form, you can use these.

If you have a large file (> 10MB), then you can use this pattern... (syntax from memory, please excuse mistype)

```
Public Class YourFormNameHere

 Private _CurrentLine as Integer = 0

 Private Sub btnClicked(sender, e) 'or enter pressed - This is YOUR keypress event handler.

  Using Dim sr as New StreamReader(filePath)

   Dim _curIndex as Integer = 0

   While (sr.EndOfFile == false)
    Dim _line as String = sr.ReadLine()         

    If (_curIndex = _CurrentLine)
      txtLineDisplay.Text = _line
      Break
    End If          

    curIndex += 1

   End While
  End Using
 End Sub
End Class
```

If you have a smaller file, then use this pattern.

```
Public Class YourFormNameHere
    
 Private _Lines as String()
 Private _CurrentLine as Integer = 0

 Private Sub formLoad(sender, e) 'one-time load event - This is YOUR form load event
  
   _Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

 End Sub

 Private Sub btnClicked(sender, e) 'or enter pressed - This is YOUR keypress event handler.

   txtLineDisplay.Text = _Lines(_CurrentLine)
   _CurrentLine += 1
   
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: the some files about 11 MB and some files 1 and less

Comment: I add Pictures but it's tell me i must have 10 reputation to add pictures

Comment: They are recommendations, not "musts". The first one (for larger files) reads from the file each time so as to not consume large amounts of memory. This will be potentially slower for the user experience, but probably the safer approach if there are going to be large files. The second one reads the file completely into memory, and may be faster for the user when navigating to the next line, but would not be recommended for larger files. 10MB may not be "too large" in your case.

Comment: in the first code i got 45 errors why ?
maybe about 30 errors for statement is not valid in a spacename

 Private _CurrentLine As Integer = 0

    Private Sub btnClicked(sender, e) 'or enter pressed

  Using (Dim sr as new StreamReader(filePath))

Comment: i solved 42 errors
there are now 3 errors
all these errors about "expression expected"

Comment: You will have to pardon some of the syntax violations. I have been working in another language for a while now and this was what I can remember from memory. Also, some of the items are intentionally pseudo code (the method signatures) and you will need to adapt the code to match.

Comment: If it helps, please post the statements that have a problem.

Comment: I told you i was solved 42 errors and these errors from statements
Thanks you

Comment: Please edit your second Code : replace `[_CurrentLine] with (_CurrentLine)